# Можно ли преобразовать число, взятое из TextView в тип Double и записать его в файл?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, типы

Я создала функцию для записи данных в файл.
В файле уже лежит некоторое число (например 2.53), мне надо считать данные из TextView и добавить их к тому, что уже лежит в файле.
Вот моя функция:

```
fun saveText(view: View?) {
        var fin: FileInputStream? = null
        fin = openFileInput(FILE_LEVEL)
        val bytes = ByteArray(fin.available())
        fin.read(bytes)
        val t = String(bytes)//данные из файла
        val t2 = kol.getText()//данные из TextView
        fin?.close()
        var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
        fos = openFileOutput(FILE_LEVEL, MODE_PRIVATE)
        fos.write(((t.toDouble() + t2.toDouble()).toString()).toByteArray())
        fos?.close()
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня подсвечивается красным цветом

```
.toDouble()
```

В интернете я нашла такую функцию, но всё равно вылетает ошибка

```
fun String.toDouble(): Double = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(this.toString())
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Comment: В метках к вопросу укажите язык программирования. Если возникают ошибки, добавьте текст ошибок.

Comment: У переменной `t2` тип `CharSequence`. Чтобы вытащить строку из `TextView`, сделайте так: `kol.getText().toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `getText()` у `TextView` возвращает `CharSequence`. Чтобы получить строку, необходимо вызвать `toString()`:

```kotlin
val text = textView.getText().toString()
```

И тогда вы сможете воспользоваться вашей функцией `fun String.toDouble()`:

```kotlin
text.toDouble()
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/634410)

Comment: Написал поподробнее.

Comment: как отменить голос не могу понять, поэтому поставил плюс ответу.